# Open default mail app using reactjs and fontawesome

Tags: reactjs

what is the best way to open the default mail app using react.js when clicking on a fontawesome envelope icon? I have tried the below with onPress but when I click the icon my default mail app doesn't open up. LinkedIn works fine and opens up in a new tab, but I'm lost with this one....please help.

```
function Twitter() {
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

return (
    <Fragment>
    <FontAwesomeIcon
    type="button"
    icon ={faLinkedinIn}
    size="4x"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open('https://www.linkedin.com');
      }}
> </FontAwesomeIcon>
    
    <FontAwesomeIcon
    type="button"
    icon ={faEnvelope}
    size="4x"
    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('email@gmail.com') }
    title="support@example.com"
  
> </FontAwesomeIcon>
    </Fragment>



);
```

}

export default Twitter;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just wrap the icon with an anchor tag as follows:

```
<a href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><FontAwesomeIcon>...</FontAwesomeIcon>
</a>
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you so much! I was confusing myself too much... (I am pretty new to react and coding in general). Thanks again!